# What is a CONTROL_REQUEST_CODE in android sdk 30?

Tags: android

```
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, CONTROL_REQUEST_CODE, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

What does the `CONTROL_REQUEST_CODE` in the `PendingIntent.getActivity` do? I'm currently making a "smart home" button feature introduced in Android 11